# Created batch cmd command hates parameters

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I seem to have kind of a problem.
playing with system files is something I really like however the batch I created to answer
  sudo make me a sandwich
properly anly half works.

```
@echo off


If %1 == make goto make

echo %1 isn't a valid argument, please check spelling and documentation

pause

stop

: make

If %2 == me goto me

echo %2 isn't a valid argument, please check spelling and documentation

pause

stop

: me

If %3 == a goto a

echo %3 isn't a valid argument, please check spelling and documentation

pause

stop

:a

If %4 == sandwich goto sandwich

echo %4 isn't a valid argument, please check spelling and documentation

pause

stop

: sandwich


echo Okay, it's done !

echo  ________________

echo /_________________\

echo ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

echo \\_________________/
```

Comment: Your sample code has no purpose - ask a specific question to solve a problem as nobody knows what you are trying to achieve from the code you have posted.

Comment: What is the error you are getting? You say it is partially working, what is working? Also following on @foxidrive comment, did you forget to add part of the code?

Comment: actually it returns the sandwich with 
sudo make me a sandwich

but fails to work properly when there are les than 4 arguments.
I located the file in C programm files common files microsoft shared windows live sudo.bat

Comment: It will only work if you enter the correct term.  For example `stop` is not a Windows command.

Comment: Is it exit then ?
what is the command to break the current running batch and get cmd to ask for new command ?

Comment: As you can see, guessing at keywords to use when programming is by far the least efficient way.

Comment: @Magaro check out the info tab for the batch-file section of SO http://stackoverflow.com/tags/batch-file/info  It has very useful links to examples and documentation for learning batch.

Comment: i'm pretty sure it "fails to work properly" with an error message or other unexpected output. study these and find enlightenment.